# Ajustar pagina web para Android con css, activar scrollbar

Tags: css, asp.net, visual-studio

estoy tratando de ajustar mi página web para visualizar en android con css pero nada más me deja mostrar la parte de arriba, pero no me permite desplazarme hacia abajo.
Tengo esta configuración en el cuerpo:

```
body {
width: 100%;
min-height: 50%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
height: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
background-image: url('Image/lukas-vandlis-643404-unsplash.jpg');
background-position: center center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
height: 100vh;
font-family: 'Heebo', sans-serif;
}
```

y para dispositivos móviles tengo (usuario es un div donde esta toda la información):

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
.usuario {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: center;

}
}
```

y me muestra así

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y abajo tengo un GridView con información.

Comment: Podrias mostrar tu html probablemente en el acomodo de las etiquetas, cabe destacar que te faltaran mas media queries css porque no solo hay un tamaño de pantalla movil

Comment: De hecho solamente tengo `<meta name="viewport" content="width=800px"/>` antes de body. Tampoco muestra el scrollbar en escritorio, supongo tiene que ver algo que agregue en body, pues fue lo ùnico que modifique pero no logro encontrar qué es.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No te permite desplazarte por el `overflow: hidden;` prueba a quitarlo.

Por otro lado... ¿Porque tienes ese meta asi? Normalmente si quieres trabajar con responsive te recomiendo algo talque:

```
< meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" >
```

Comment: Si, gracias. Ya me eh dado cuenta de ese error.